# How add new options to the dock icon menu

Tags: macos, qt, menu, dock

There are some default options that appear when a macOS application in added to the dock like *Quit*, *Hide*, *Show in Finder*, etc.

I want to add few more options to the dock menu for my Qt application.

I'm unable to find any artifacts that Qt provides to configure the dock menu.

Is it possible to do so using Qt?

[image: dock menu icon's context menu]

Answer (score 0):

```
m_menu = new QMenu(0);
m_editerAction = new QAction("Hello");
m_menu->addAction(d_ptr->m_editerAction);
m_menu->setAsDockMenu();
```